# Extract text from PDF at bookmark

Tags: java, pdf

I need to extract the text from a PDF right at the place where a bookmark is.

PDFBox extracts the whole page where the bookmark is, as explained [here](http://www.pdfbox.org/userguide/text_extraction.html#Advanced+Text+Extraction) .

But i need to extract the text **starting** with the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe iText can handle this.

```
Rectangle2D bookmarkRect = getRectFromBookmark(someBookmarkThingy);

FilteredTextRenderListener filter = 
  new FilteredTextRenderListener( new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), 
                                  new RegionTextRenderFilter( bookmarkRect ));

String bookmarkText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, pageNum, filter);
```

`someBookmarkThingy` will probably be a PdfDictionary of the bookmark in question.

**WARNING** Bookmarks can actually hold just about any action.  They typically hold one of several varieties of GoTo* action.

GoTo actions can specify a rectangle, an upper left corner & zoom factor, just a page, and quite a few other variants.  Anything defining a zoom setting *will be affected by the size of the window the PDF is being displayed in*.  That includes all of them except the one that explicitly defines a bounding box for the new view.  You'll have to make an educated guess on what a typical window size is and do your conversions from there.

You're probably going to need to read the [PDF Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), particularly section 12.6.4.2 "Go-To Actions".  Hmph.  What you really need will be the section on Destinations, 12.3.2.  Page destinations can be defined thusly:

- [pageRef /XYZ left top zoom]
- [pageRef /Fit]
- [pageRef /FitH top]
- [pageRef /FitV left]
- [pageRef /FitR left bottom right top]
- [pageRef /FitB]
- [pageRef /FitBH top]
- [pageRef /FitBV left]

Have fun!

Comment: And don't forget that the bottom of a page doesn't have to be Y=0.  It could be 200 or -2000.  You just need to check the page's crop box (and rotation!).